# How to install zram on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: installation, zram

I tried to install zRam using the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shnatsel/zram
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zramswap-enabler
```

But it throws the following error message which says that the package is not available:

```
E: Couldn't find package zramswap-enabler
```

I tried to download and install the zramswap-enabler_0.2.1-0~12~oneiric1_all.deb package, but after the second reboot it stops working.

Answer (score 13):

To install zRAM, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install zram-config
```

Once the installation is done go ahead and reboot your machine.

To check whether it works:

```
cat /proc/swaps
```

You can download it [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zram-config).

And to install

```
sudo dpkg -i zram-config_0.5_all.deb
```

Or use [Gdebi](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gdebi)

Comment: Just to clarify... you don't need to install zramswap-enabler or the ppa, the zram-config package is a meta-package containing the upstart job for it. If you want to verify that it is working, type mount at the command prompt and you'll see more fuse mounted partitions than before.

Comment: User above claims that you don't need to restart, can you confirm?

Comment: That's right you don't, but it won't hurt that you do, I do it out of habit.

Comment: You do not need to reboot the machine, it's just a waste of time. Nice to see a moderator delete what I have already said and repeat it so that he can get all the credit.

Comment: Also works in 13.10. To configure the size of the swap (which defaults to half the memory) you can edit /etc/init/zram-config.conf.

Comment: Strange. In Lubuntu 17.04 I have to reboot to make it work. That was never needed before

Comment: E: Unable to locate package zram-config . This does not work

Comment: @KansaiRobot Take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt), to help youwith the install.  Also you can download it [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zram-config).

Answer (score 0):

zramswap-enabler hasn't been released for 13.04 yet. Unless you can make an updated version yourself, you'll have to wait for Shnatsel to release one (this is according to https://launchpad.net/~shnatsel/+archive/zram, which only lists packages up to Quantal).