# "Unable to locate package" while trying to install packages with APT

Tags: apt, package-management

When I try to install any package through the command line, I get an error.

```
$ sudo apt-get install <package>
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package <package>
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: This is coming up a lot recently because 18.04 Server has universe, multiverse, and backports disabled by default.

Comment: Is there a launchpad issue for improving the helpful hint given when entering a command not installed?  (Just hinting that it is in a repository not enabled would be very helpful)

Comment: This is something I hit a lot when I am building containers, usually with both Docker and Singularity. In Singularity containers you have different BootStrap options, among them being `debootstrap` and `docker`. For some reason, if I use `debootstrap` to start with a base Ubuntu image (e.g. `xenial`), I hit this error where some packages cannot be found with `apt-get`. The solution ends up being to switch to the `docker` BootStrap, then it functions again.

Comment: @Jackalope Then maybe the package name is incorrect or you need to run `sudo apt update`. Use `apt-cache search` followed by a search term to search for the correct package name.

Comment: I've done those things. I've triple-checked the name of the package (libsdl2-2.0-0), & verified availability with apt-cache search. I was eventually able to get this package installed by installing the docs, which appears to have installed the package as a dependency.

Comment: It might have been a caching issue, if the search command returned the package correctly. In my case the cache issue was due to a `RUN --mount` in a Docker-file. See [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259978/ubuntu-unable-to-locate-package#comment136698706_17259978).

Answer (score 229, accepted):

First, check if the package actually does exist:

1. Go to [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) with a web browser.
2. Scroll down to "Search package directories"
3. Enter  the package which you're trying to install into the "Keyword" field.

   Enable "Only show exact matches:"

   Change the "Distribution" to the codename of the version of Ubuntu you're using, e.g. *focal* in Ubuntu 20.04 or it's displayed by `lsb_release -sc`

   > [image: Search package direction. Keyword search box: "unity", with buttons for "Search" and "Reset". Followed by options for "Search on", with "Package names only" selected (with "descriptions" and "Source package names" being the other options). A checkbox for "Only show exact matches" is ticked. A "distribution" dropdown has "raring" selected, and a "section" dropdown is set to "any".]

If there are **no results**, the package you are looking for doesn't exist and the next steps will not work. It may require a third party PPA or an alternative installation method.

**If** results **are found**, the package exists and you may continue with these steps:

1. Open *Software Sources* (or *Software & Updates* in 13.04+) by searching for it in the Dash.
2. Open the "Ubuntu Software" tab.
3. Ensure that the first 4 checkboxes on this tab are enabled:

> [image: Software & Updates panel, on the "Ubuntu Software" tab. There are five options in "Downloadable from the internet", all selected: Canonical-supported free and open-source software (main); Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe); Proprietary drivers for devices (restricted); Software restricted by copyright or legal issues (multiverse); Source code. A "Download from" dropdown is set to "Main server".]

4. Update the package lists, then test with these commands:

   ```
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install <TEST_PACKAGE>
   ```

Comment: I found that a simple `sudo apt-get update` was enough to fix it for me. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` also worked for me on Ubuntu on Windows 10 (this is important because the UI referenced in the latter half of this answer doesn't exist on that system).

Comment: Don't forget to search http://launchpad.net as well!

Comment: In my case i only needed to enable the text boxes and it worked after an update ...

Comment: I'm running my server from the shell, and can't open GUIs. Is it possible to solve this with command line only?

Comment: @UlyssesAlves Pandya's answer gives the solution for the command line.

Comment: You helped me when I was installing singularity on Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks.

Comment: I found I had to add the line  `deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu focal main universe`  to my  /etc/apt/sources.list  file before running  `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 124):

There are many [questions](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=Unable+to+locate+package) about this topic. Here I provide a basic/general answer.

When `apt-get install` is unable to locate a package, the package you want to install couldn't be found within repositories that you have added (those in in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`).

The following (general) procedure helps to solve this:

1. **Make sure you have enabled Ubuntu repositories:**

   To enable all repositories (`main`, `universe`, `restricted`, `multiverse`), use the following commands:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository main
   sudo add-apt-repository universe
   sudo add-apt-repository restricted
   sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
   ```

   Visit [Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) for more information.
2. **For finding PPA for more packages:**

   - Go to [Ubuntu Package Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/). <sup>(Already explained in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/378565/256099) answer)</sup>
   - If the package that you are unable to locate is from a PPA go to the PPA and check if it is available there for your release.
   - For External Repositories, Visit [Ubuntu Updates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/) and search by
     [image: screen] button. or Visit
     [PPAs](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppas).
   - Or Search in [Launchpad ppa](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas)
   - Find appropriate ppa **according to your Ubuntu release version.**
3. **Add PPA (by command-line)**:

   Use this command:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:<repository-name>
   ```

   Visit [Ubuntu community help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine) for more information.
4. **Don't forget to update** (make apt aware of your changes):

   It is essential to run this command after changing any repositories:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   Selecting [best download server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Download_Server) may help to speed up update.
5. **Finally install the package:**

   ```
   sudo apt-get install <package>
   ```

   Refer to [Package management by commandline](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto).

**Additional/Tip**: you can find the correct package-name (i.e the name in the repository) using `apt-cache search <package-name>`.

---

- Related frequently asked Q&A:

1. [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/q/140246/256099)
2. [What does "Package <package> has no installation candidate" mean?](https://askubuntu.com/q/14685/256099)

---

**Note**: If package is not available on repository any how,  than you have to wait until it is available (in the case of new/updated versions) or use other installation processes than `apt-get` e.g. compiling from source, downloading executable binary, etc.

Comment: It could also be that the user is searching for `libname`, when it's `libname2` in Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: First, is depends on the package and you are making a number of assumptions. First, you are assuming the OP has identified the correct package name, as pointed out by saiarcot895 . Second you are assuming the packages is available. In general, it is best to first identify the problem. Then if at all possible install from the repositories. Unless there is a specific need, ppa is a second choice. If the package is not in the repositories or ppa it may need to be compiled from source. You really do not have enough information.

Comment: @saiarcot895 @bodhi.zazen : Revised answer with providing `apt-cache search` to find correct package-name from repositories.

Comment: I accidentally deleted the whole thing: meaning I removed all repositories, which I can imagine other people might have done as well, especially if you're cleaning up your repo list slightly too enthusiastically

Answer (score 16):

## Fresh Ubuntu installation?

Many times just updating the package lists from all repositories and PPA's does the trick:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This should be the ***first*** thing to do.

If this does not work you need search for the repository or PPA which contains the package you are after, add it, and run `sudo apt-get update` again. Steps for the process are well explained on the other answers on this page.

Answer (score 9):

[xbmc](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xbmc) is only available in the [universe repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu), only since Ubuntu 12.04 (precise). If you have an older release of Ubuntu, you'll need to upgrade or to get xbmc from another place.

If you have Ubuntu 12.04, make sure that you have [turned on the universe repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Adding_Ubuntu_Software_Repositories). You can see what repositories you have enabled in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` (and in files in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`). Check that this file contains a line like

```
deb http://al.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
```

or

```
deb http://zw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
```

If you only find a line like

```
deb http://mn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
```

and no line with `universe`, add `universe` at the end of that line, or a separate line with `precise universe`, as illustrated above.

If you need to modify `/etc/apt/sources.list`, run `sudo apt-get update` afterwards, then try installing again. If the package is still not found, post the complete content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the output of `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: @EliahKagan I hadn't thought my answer could be interpreted that way, I tried to clarify. Why not `al` and `zw`? (I try to select an appropriate mirror for the OP when they give a clue, but here I have no idea.)

Answer (score 6):

I'm new to Ubuntu but i'm writing this as I discovered some solutions to avoid this "Unable to Locate Package" errors. There are three circumstances where this might occur to a shock.

1. After installing Ubuntu if you don't update it followed by Upgrades, This might occur.
2. If there are plenty of software updates to occur in future, make sure all important security updates/recommended updates are turned off by typing "**Update Manager**" on pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.
3. Issue One and Two can happen even after updating or clearing all updates. But the eternal solution is:
   Try point 1 & 2, then type `sudo apt-get killmanager`, if not working no problem proceed to type `sudo apt-get update`, then type `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Now you should be able to install any software through Terminal.

Comment: If You still get error on "sudo apt-get update" line, try using "sudo apt-get upgrade". This will work.. Guys !! As Linux is highly case sensitive Please make sure you use all commands in smaller letters like "sudo" instead of "Sudo"

Answer (score 6):

In the case where tried to install a file:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++.so.6
```

instead of a package. You get the error message:

> ```
> E: Unable to locate package libstdc++.so.6
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libstdc++.so.6'
> ```

because you tried to install a file `libstdc++.so.6` that you can't install, because it is located in a debian package.

You can use `apt-file` to search for the package that contains that file. To install it, type:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

Then you have to update the index.

```
sudo apt-file update
```

After that, you can search for the package which contains the file `libstdc++.so.6`:

```
sudo apt-file find libstdc++.so.6
```

Then you find a lot packages that contains the searched file. For this example I paste only one search result:

```
libstdc++6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

Then you can install the needed package `libstdc++6`:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

Answer (score 3):

you must supply either full path or relative path to reach the xxx.deb file

```
# bad way since PATH env var does not 
# and should not contain the '.' (current) directory
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb 

sudo apt-get install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb # proper way
```

notice in above I supply the relative path to reach the xxx.deb file as in ./xxx.deb
this is an intentional security measure to prevent `sudo` from installing a rogue xxx.deb from a potentially polluted PATH variable

below also works ... its using full path to reach the file

```
sudo apt-get install /tmp/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```