# Command to open new tab in the current terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Is it possible to open a new tab in the current terminal with some commands?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

### If you just want to open a new tab

To open a new tab in the current opened terminal you can press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
Alternatively, use the top level menu, which shows the keyboard shortcut (see screenshot below)

### If you want to do it from the command line

Install `xdotool` - a program that lets you simulate keyboard input (among other things).

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

then type in the terminal:

```
xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
```

That will simulate pressing the key combination, and open the new tab in the terminal.

[image]

Comment: Great answer, really easy to follow. How would one make a shortcut for switching to the next/previous tab? This would help immensely.

Comment: What window theme are you using? Really like it

Comment: Thats I am not using right now. Its long ago. not sure I didnt remember the name.@xoner

Comment: @Goran_Mandic I found it is now possible with SHIFT+CTRL+arrow key.

Comment: @Goran_Mandic you can also use alt + a number to switch between terminal tabs. like if you have three tabs they would be 1,2,3 from left to right. alt + 1 would open the leftmost tab.

Comment: There is no need for xdotools. ctrl+shift+t opens a new tab in the default ubuntu terminal with no modifications necessary.

Comment: For me it is not a satisfying "command line" option if evetually the solution fakes a GUI input instead. This is at best a workaround, with the ill effect that it eases the desire for a real command line solution like: `gnome-terminal --add-new-tab`. Also a key press combination is not a command line

Comment: @user137717 the question does ask for a command line, not a keyboard shortcut, therefore you need `xdotools`.

Comment: hwo to switch between tabs in terminal

Comment: can be open a new tab using  command without using `xdotools`

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 users will face an issue to install xdotool. https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt. follow the steps mentioned in to install xdotool.

Answer (score 80):

In Gnome Terminal Emulator just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

You can check and change this and other key combinations in Edit menu.

Comment: The question searches for a command and not for a shortcut.

Comment: I'd love to be able to `cntrl+tab` between the tabs

Comment: @JamieHutber You can use Ctrl+PgUp and Ctrl+PgDn

Answer (score 24):

in the terminal the shortcut key is

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

this shortcut can also be edited

Comment: that is not a command line solution, but a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: hwo to switch between tabs in terminal ?

Comment: For switching tabs between terminal use CTRL + PAGEUP/PAGEDOWN

Answer (score 21):

New tab <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Close tab: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

Switch tab: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pg Dn</kbd>

Move tab: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Pg Dn</kbd>

Comment: Where are the command line commands?

Answer (score 7):

Huh, I do this to fork a build process.  package.sh builds and uploads docker images - so I prefer them to overlap.  `gnome-terminal` has some command line options to make new tabs:

```
#!/bin/bash
BRANCH=${1?choose an environment e.g. stage, demo, production}

if [ -x "$(command -v gnome-terminal)" ]; then
  # run in parallel for gnome-terminal
  gnome-terminal \
  --tab --working-directory=`pwd` --command "zsh -is eval './package.sh app1 $BRANCH'" \
  --tab --working-directory=`pwd` --command "zsh -is eval 'sleep 75  && ./package.sh app2 $BRANCH'" \
  --tab --working-directory=`pwd` --command "zsh -is eval 'sleep 150 && ./package.sh app3 $BRANCH'" \
  --tab --working-directory=`pwd` --command "zsh -is eval 'sleep 225 && ./package.sh app4 $BRANCH'" \

else
  # run one at a time for bash
  ./package.sh app1 $BRANCH
  ./package.sh app2 $BRANCH
  ./package.sh app3 $BRANCH
  ./package.sh app4 $BRANCH

fi
```

Comment: This is the best answer. No need for installing extra tools and simulating keystrokes

Comment: yes `gnome-terminal --tab` do the job, thanks. Note than `--command` is legacy, use `--` to finish, then your-command, sample: `gnome-terminal --tab -- yarn dev`

Answer (score 3):

Use package [ttab](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttab)

Edit like this

```
ttab 'cd /Users/chenkai/gh/g-imagery-api && npm run dev '
```

Comment: Please, provide a more detailed answer, include more specific commands and not just link to another solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open a new tab to a **specific directory**:

1. [Set the shortcut to Switch to Last Tab](https://askubuntu.com/a/1178258/356625) in your terminal Preferences.
2. Put the shortcut to the command below.

   ```
   gnome-terminal --tab --working-directory=$HOME/path/to/the/dir; xdotool key <Switch to Last Tab shortcut>
   ```

Make sure you have xdotool installed.

Answer (score 1):

The way i usually want to do this is when i start typing `cd some/directory/to-switch-to` and then i realize i would much rather open that directory in a new tab.  This function will open a new tab in the same directory if no path is specified, and in the specified directory (absolute, home-relative, or current directory relative) if one is supplied, with much credit to [@wolcen](https://agaric.coop/wolcen).

```bsh
tcd() {
  if [ -d ${PWD}/$1 ]; then
    gnome-terminal --tab --working-directory=${PWD}/$1
  else      
    gnome-terminal --tab --working-directory=$1
  fi
}
```

Usage example:

`tcd some/directory`

Now if i've finished typing a `cd` command i can press `ctrl+a` and `t` and `ENTER` to instead open the directory in a new tab with just a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

- Open the terminal
- maximize it (or just click the terminal window)
- at top bar, click **Terminal**-->**Preferences**
- under **General** option, switch **Window** to **Tab**
- after that, whenever you want to open new terminal, RightClick in the terminal --> **Open Terminal**

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal way on *Nix to open new Window(s) or Tab(s) on and execute bash command(s), on all the different distros and flavours out there: Gnome, KDE, XWindows, Windows Terminal (WSL), MacOS and the list goes on.

Each window manager and flavour comes with its own Terminal / Console app, and they all have different command line arguments, behaviours and quirks.

As far as I know, the closest you can get are:

### [*neWin*](https://github.com/anodynos/newin): Windows WSL & KDE Konsole

Opens multiple new Window(s) or Tab(s) on Windows Terminal (WSL) or KDE Konsole and optionally executes bash command(s).

Works as-is in both KDE Linux and WSL, with no code changes. Example:

```
$ npm i -g newin

$ newin 
# open a new window, waiting for input command

$ newin --workdir '~/myproject' 'npm start:watch' 'npm test:watch'
# executes the first command on a new window and the second on another one.
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of neWin - looking for help to add more flavors!

### [wttab](https://github.com/lalilaloe/wttab): Windows WSL & Powershell only

Programmatically open Windows Terminal tab or windows

```
$ npm i -g wttab
$ wttab --window --workdir '~/myproject' 'ls -all' 
# executes the command on a new window
```

### [ttab](https://github.com/mklement0/ttab): MacOS & gnome-terminal only

Similar to wttab "a CLI for Unix-like platforms that programmatically opening a new terminal tab/window in one of the following terminal applications, optionally with a command to execute". Unfortunatelly, Ttab has [no plans to add support for other platforms](https://github.com/mklement0/ttab/issues/11).

```
$ npm i -g ttab

$ ttab ls -l "$HOME/Library/Application Support"
# Open a new tab and execute the specified command before showing the prompt.
```