# Command to switch to the last terminal tab

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

Is there a way to switch to the last terminal tab with some commands or bash script?

What I have got so far:

- To switch to the next tab:

  ```
  xdotool key ctrl+Page_Down
  ```
- To [get the number of terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/132587/307359) tabs:

  ```
  let terminal_counts=$(ls /dev/pts/  | wc -l)-1
  ```

Now I need to know how many times I need to execute `xdotool key ctrl+Page_Down`. How to know the current tab number?

Comment: You didn't mention it but `Ctrl`+`PageUp` takes you to the previous terminal tab (but not the last terminal tab).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In gnome-terminal.. there is inbuilt function without assigning any shortcut key..

you can assign a shortcut key by Selecting Edit -- >> Preferences -- >> Shortcuts -->> Switch to Last Tab and by pressing valid key/ key combination like below

[image: Hi]