# Alternative/Indicator to Dash search bar

Tags: software-recommendation, indicator, unity-dash, alternative

Is there any Alternative/Indicator to Dash search for searching and opening applications & files?

How to install it in Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Indicator-Synapse** is spotlight-like search bar.

You can install by following command in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-synapse
```

After installation logout and login back to see indicator in panel:
[image: screen]

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and use arrow keys to move to indicator-synapse.

---

If you want classical navigation type indicator then install **Classic Menu Indicator**:

```
sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator
```

[image: classical]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this search also working for directories or just for applications?

Comment: `Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to locate package indicator-synapse`

Comment: i am getting the above error when installing `indicator-synapse`

Comment: @PankajGautam Visit instructions for [Unable to locate package](http://askubuntu.com/q/378558/256099) error.