# How to pin Unity-Dash on Plank dock bar ? Alternatives to Dash?

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

I am new to Linux and have some questions about how to customize my Unity GUI.

I have installed Ubuntu with Unity GUI. I had `Unity` launcher bar and installed `Plank` as alternative and moved the dock bar on left side of the screen. The problem is that when I press the hot-key for Dash the whole launcher bar appears and overflow my `Plank` bar. On aesthetic point of view it really annoys me.

- Is there any way to pin the Dash icon on the `Plank` bar?
- Can I make some way, when I press the Dash hot-key only Dash screen to
  appear without this Unity launcher to show up ?
- Are there any alternative application similar to `Unity Dash` that I can pin
  to my `Plank` and set up hot-key for them ?

I am looking for something similar to [Cairo Docker's Application Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Wb3r.jpg), which does pretty much the same thing as Dash and pin it to `Plank`.

Comment: I think this was answered here: 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/500209/alternative-indicator-to-dash-search-bar