# How to install xnviewmp in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, xnview

I'm trying to install [XnView multi platform](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/) on my Kubuntu 14.04.

It is available in the Ubuntu apps directory (see [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xnviewmp/)) but apturl - as well as apt-get install xnviewmp - gives the error unable to find the package.

Can't figure out what went wrong!

Any ideas?

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Release: 14.04

Codename: trusty

sources.list file: http://pastebin.com/EZBbta7m

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/805269/25388

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dhor/myway
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xnview
```

[image]

Or you can download the.deb file [here](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/#downloads), and install it.  I would use Gdebi to install, if you don't have it just do

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

You can install it from there, but its an **older version 0.51**.  To install from there, just click

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: Thank you but I knew about that PPA.. How come that XnView is listed in the Ubuntu apps directory and we can not simply install it from there?

Comment: See additions in my answer.

Comment: Thank you man but I knew about the PPA and the download from the XnView's website. What I was asking is why I could not install it from the official repositories of Ubuntu? (both sudo apt-get install xnviewmp and the Ubuntu Software Center (from [the link you gave me](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/trusty/xnviewmp/)) give me the error package not found)! (Canonical partners, Ubuntu Extras, Main, Universe, Multiverse.. are all activated)

Comment: What you could try is to regenerate your sources.list. Visit [Ubuntu Sources List Generator](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/).  After that run `sudo apt-get update`, and try again.  You can also take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-for-all-packages

Comment: Still the same thing even after checking all the repos.. Thank you anyway I've downloaded the deb from the website and installed it that way. :-)