# How to Install XnView in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, image-viewers, xnview

I download the .deb 64 bit image in their [homepage](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/#downloads), untar and install. Launching the app by the icon is unsuccessful and also in terminal

```
/opt/XnView/XnView: error while loading shared libraries: libgstapp-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I do not want to add third-party repositories to my system like in the proposal of the thread for 14.04, since the official image must work if at all.
I forwarded this thread already to the developer.

System: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid
XnView: 0.81
Softwares: `gstreamer`
Related: [XNViewMP broken on Ubuntu 16.04](http://newsgroup.xnview.com/viewtopic.php?f=62&t=33074), [XnView startet nicht](https://debianforum.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=159906), [How to install xnviewmp in ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/511875/25388)

Comment: Hey same here. I downloaded 64bit .deb file from their official website and installed via terminal. Seems like it get installed but clicking on icon doesn't do anything. I was like this is only with me. Now going for Gimp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution based on the German thread about the issue

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
```

Application starts successfully without apparent failures.