# Installation error from terminal and ubuntu software center

Tags: software-installation, sublime-text

I am trying to install sublime using terminal but it pop out error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sublime
```

And when I try to install `vlc` from Ubuntu Software Center then also I can't install since there is no install icon.

Upon execution of `sudo apt-get update` terminal pops out following output

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) 
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Comment: enable `multiverse` and `universe` in software sources in software updates.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-by-apt

This question has already been answered here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The output :

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) 
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Points to the file `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock` which is created when you use `sudo apt-get install` and `sudo apt-get update` command. This file prevents multiple `apt-get` calls and is automatically removed after the command execution has completed. But sometimes it doesn't get removed, and to do that manually,

This set of code needs to be executed.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try again.

Source : ["Unable to locate package" while trying to install packages with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-by-apt) |
[Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

Comment: Deleting system files is very dangerous. While it might sometimes be the best course of action, it certainly shouldn't be a first resort.

Comment: I agree but /var/lib/apt/lists/lock file needed to be removed to execute `sudo apt-get update`. I've also added the link to the possible duplicate in a comment. @evilsoup

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are trying to install Sublime Text, it is not in the [official Ubuntu repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sublime). Install Sublime Text 3 using the package from [their site](http://www.sublimetext.com/3).

Comment: Thank you! it worked :)