# How to install packages in ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, package-management

I have tried to install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and `vlc`,
 but I'm getting this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
[sudo] password for aashay: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras

$ sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vlc
```

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install vlc`. Also, which version of Ubuntu  are you using.

Comment: which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: That is only about installing packages, not related to video players, right? (Your own first example also was something different.)

Comment: yeah, I have tried that. Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Comment: Did you try `update` first, before `install`?

Comment: yeah, I have even tried that also, but some updates just got failed.

Comment: Give the answer here a try: [“Unable to locate package” while trying to install packages by apt](http://askubuntu.com/q/378558/36315)

Answer (score 0):

To install the latest vlc version :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:djcj/vlc-stable

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: VLC package is available in official repositories for Ubuntu 14.04, don't need to add its PPA.

Comment: Never add PPA's you don't know, or trust. Specially when vlc is available in the official repo!