# how do I install Aptitude on Ubuntu

Tags: aptitude

I was trying to install MemCached using this command: `sudo aptitude install memcached`, but I got the following error: `sudo: aptitude: command not found`.

After researching, I found out that Aptitude is an utility program to manipulate files, install out uninstall programs. I found several web pages explaining what Aptitude. However, I don't have the impression that any of them explains how to get Aptitude in the first place.

Is Aptitude already in Ubuntu so that I just need to enable it. Or should I download and install it?

Thanks for helping

Comment: `sudo: aptitude: command not found` is not a command. Copy & paste error? Just use `sudo apt-get install memecached`.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install aptitude`

Comment: @Raptor: I pasted the wrong text. Now,the right text it there.

Comment: Different? More like the instructions you are following are incomplete. I prefer `aptitude` too but the default tool is `apt-get`.

Answer (score 40):

Answer from the comments (poster Osborn doesn't seem to have an AU account):

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Comment: ```Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package aptitude is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'aptitude' has no installation candidate
```
This doesn't work on Ubuntu 16

Comment: @dylanh724 https://askubuntu.com/a/378565/158442

Answer (score 3):

You may need to update your sources first:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install aptitude
```