# Difference between package and source on http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Tags: apt

I wonder what difference there is between source and package at the top left corner here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/utopic/devel/gcc

It says:

```
- Source: gcc-defaults
- Package: gcc
```

I am aware of what the source of a program is, but here I am confused.

I don't know what to do if for instance I want to install gfortran:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/utopic/gfortran

It says the same :

```
- Source: gcc-defaults
- Package: gfortran
```

A `sudo apt-get install gfortran` simply doesn't work, while `sudo apt-get install gcc` does.

Comment: Command `sudo apt-get install gfortran` should worked. Post output.

Comment: @Pandya `E: Unable to locate package gfortran`

Comment: that is another question visit [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/378558/256099) follow [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/481355/256099)(s) help you

Comment: @Pandya I don't understand in which way this link addresses the question. The question remains: why does `sudo apt-get install gcc` work and not `sudo apt-get install gfortran` ? I hope I'm not missing any point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit [ubuntuupdates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/utopic/main/base/gcc-defaults):

> **Package "gcc-defaults"**
>
> This package is just an umbrella for a group of other packages, it has no description.
>   Description samples from packages in group:
>
> ```
> GNU C preprocessor (cpp)
> Documentation for the GNU C preprocessor (cpp)
> GNU C++ compiler
> GNU C++ compiler (multilib files)
> ```
>
> Packages in group
>
> cpp cpp-doc g++ g++-multilib gcc
>   gcc-doc gcc-multilib gccgo-doc gcj-jdk gcj-jre
>   gcj-jre-headless gfortran gfortran-doc gfortran-multilib gobjc
>   libgcj-bc libgcj-common libphobos-dev

Hence **`gcc-defaults` is head/source/umbrella package for `gcc`, `gfortran` etc.**