# Problem with installing testdisk in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, software-installation, data-recovery, testdisk

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but by mistake I deleted all partition. Now I want to recover the lost memory by installing `testdisk` . But when I try to execute the command `sudo apt-get install testdisk` in Terminal I get this error message:

```
Unable to locate package testdisk
```

Why does this occur and what can I do next?

Comment: Do not use your disk any more, and follow my answer there: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu

Comment: Are you positive your partitions were all deleted? Maybe the bootloader was just changed... If you're still running Ubuntu, or running a live dvd/usb, the command `sudo parted -l` (and maybe `fdisk -l` if you're using MBR) should list all your local disk partitions & current device names

Answer (score 0):

Probably jsut need to do a

```
sudo apt-get update
```

first, and if testdisk's still not available you may need to use the universe, restricted, multiverse "sections" of the repos, see the possible dup. question ["Unable to locate package" while trying to install packages with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-by-apt) or [Ubuntu's Repositories help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu).

But are you positive your partitions were all deleted? Maybe the bootloader was just changed... If you're still running Ubuntu, or running a live dvd/usb, the command
`sudo parted -l`
(and maybe `sudo fdisk -l` if you're using MBR only) should list all your local disk partitions & current device names, maybe they're still there.

If they were all deleted, then further writing to the disk could overwrite more data, and doing as Takkat suggests would be the best idea. I don't think you can repair a hard disk with `testdisk` while it's mounted anyway, and having a backup copy to "play/fix" with would be the safest option.