# Unity8 Development install troubleshooting

Tags: application-development, development, unity8

First attempt at getting into development with Unity and in a Linux box.  I was able to pull down the trunk and (I think) build its dependancies, but it doesn't feel like I've done this right and I don't think this is actually working.

First, according to their site https://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity8/ running `./build -setup`, I get the error `-bash: ./build: No such file or directory`.  It only works (I think) `./build.sh`.

Also, when it builds, I get 
`E: Unable to locate package pay-service
E: Unable to locate package qml-module-qtquick-layouts
E: Unable to locate package qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel
E: Unable to locate package qml-module-ubuntu-connectivity`

And finally, when I do `./run.sh` I get `initctl: Unknown job: unity8
Unity8 is already running, please stop it first`, however, when I type `unity --version` I get `unity 7.2.4`

Is there something that I'm missing?  I've tried looking around and haven't really found anything that's detailed about starting up a development environment for Unity.  All my development experience I have was done through SVN on a Windows-based machine (and some Git based SourceTree).

Comment: For Unable to locate package error, [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/378558) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `./build.sh --setup`, it appears we left the *.sh* off the end of that step. The *--setup* should pull in all those other dependencies.