# Problems installing postgresql-9.4: Unable to locate package

Tags: 14.04, apt, downloads, postgresql

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I'm trying to download postgresql using [this guide](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/).

But when I run the command `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4` in my terminal, I get this error message:

```
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.4
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.4'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/621663/edit) your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy postgresql`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: Remember to do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` before installing.

Comment: Have you set repository as given [there](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/)? Also visit http://askubuntu.com/q/378558

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because in Ubuntu 14.04 repositories there is postgresql-9.3 version. So run

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3
```

Comment: I got back "E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)."

Comment: So run "sudo apt-get install -f".

Comment: Not "sudo apt-get -f install"?

Comment: It does not matter.

Comment: By the way, I think that the 14.04 version (no LTS) is no longer supported. This answer won't work. On the other hand, today, I installed postgresql-9.4+postgis-2.1 in Debian 8. In my Ubuntu 14.10 it was unfunctional because there are two libgdal versions totally incompatible. If you have the last R version with rgdal it is probable that QGIS will be broken. I experienced that. The same problem with postgres+postgis.

Comment: 14.04 IS LTS. And it is supported till April 2019.

Comment: So what if you want to use the 9.4 version, which actually have the functionality (jsonb) that I need?

Comment: this saved my ass. thanks a lot. tried 9.6, 9.4 , 9.2 to no avail. hahaha

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. Note what @Mattis said above - 9.4 is required for `:jsonb`. This answer is basically like "just deal with it, you dont get 9.4" which is in no way helpful to those whom need 9.4

@TimSolo has the correct answer, which should be accepted.

Answer (score 24):

You can install postgres 9.4 on Ubuntu 14.04!

Follow the instructions on http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/:

> Create the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list`, and add a line
>   for the repository:
>
> ```
> deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main
> ```
>
> Import the repository signing key, and update the package lists:
>
> ```
> wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | \
>   sudo apt-key add -
> sudo apt-get update
> ```

Now you can install with

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4
```

Comment: how do i execute this. coming from a windows noob user. can you give me commands to type line by line in the cmd

Comment: @noogui literally just copy paste the above in your terminal. To "create the file" just type `sudo touch  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list` or use a program like `vim`, `nano`, or `emacs`. In that file youve created, just add the one single line starting with `deb` - that is the location of the postgres package repository. Then just copy the rest of the commands above and paste it into your terminal - it will add the authentication key for your system and that repository. Run the final command above to install the 9.4 package from the repository.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, helps users on other platforms such as Debian or other versions of Ubuntu altogether.