# apt-get detects no package

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, troubleshooting

I have a problem which is probably linked to the internet problems.

I have an ubuntu 14.04 LTS as a partition on MBP, and I have very recently got the Wi-Fi driver working. However, it is very slow. Sometimes, it even does not detect the server. This behavior is probably linked to the main problem. Whenever I try to install any package using `apt-get install` I can think of, I get this type of error (for example):

```
$ sudo apt-get install squid3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package squid3
```

And when I try issuing `squid3` into the Terminal, it shows:

```
The program 'squid3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install squid3
```

The same error applies to all the packages I can think of. Is this because the access to ubuntu being blocked? Is it a different issue?

Comment: What does "sudo apt-get update" command show?

Comment: Whoops. I flagged my question because I found an identical one [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-by-apt)