# Unable to locate package libffi-dev

Tags: software-installation, 15.04

I'm trying to install weasyprint on Ubuntu, and am running into the following error with libffi-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libffi-dev
```

I'm not sure what I could possibly be doing wrong, however without this I keep failing whenever I try to install weasyprint. Can someone help me out?

Comment: what is output of command `apt-cache search libffi`?

Comment: libffi6 - Foreign Function Interface library runtime

Comment: did you make `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: I make my comments as answer check it

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Unable to locate package" while trying to install packages by apt](http://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-by-apt)

Answer (score 4):

Check this entry in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid main restricted universe
```

Start an update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And install with

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

---

The Package is in the main repositories:

```
% apt-cache policy libffi-dev
libffi-dev:
  Installed: 3.2.1-2
  Candidate: 3.2.1-2
  Version table:
 *** 3.2.1-2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 2):

Addthis entry in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` if it'snot

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid main restricted universe
```

update soures list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then try again

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

If you, like me, can't install from the repo because you are on an unsupported version of Ubuntu and can't change ATM, try installing the `deb` package manually:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libffi

I needed `libffi-dev` to install a gem, and so I downloaded:

> libffi-dev-dbgsym_3.2.1-6_amd64.ddeb (872 bytes)

Installed that, and was able to then `bundle install` and the gem works.