# How to install QGIS server?

Tags: package-management, qgis

I am trying to install QGIS Server following this [link](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_server_support.html). But I am faced with the following output:

[image]

I cannot figure out how to continue from here. Please help

**UPDATE**
I work on Ubuntu 14.04 installed on VMWare Player on Windows 10.

I tried to install the missing packages directly but I got the following output for `libqgis-analysis2.12.3`:

[image]

When I try to install `` I get this output:

[image]

Here is my /etc/apt/sources.list :
[image]

Here is the output of the `apt-cache policy libqgis-analysis*`:

[image]

Comment: Have you locate the python-qgi package? is that possible to locate it by http://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-by-apt

Comment: The package name appears to be `python-qgis` - you seem to have written `python-qgi`

Comment: @steeldriver: you are right, but the error still there after correct it

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @Raphael I am working with 14.04

Comment: I [checked](http://qgis.org/debian/pool/main/q/qgis/), and ``ligqgis-analysis2.12.3``, for example, is available for Trusty. Have you tried to install those packages directly (``apt-get install``)? Also, I notice it is asking for a specific package (``qgis-providers``), apparently from [ubuntugis](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ppa/). Do you have that PPA installed?

Comment: @Suda.nese - Please share the output of `apt-cache policy libqgis-analysis*`

Comment: @carnendil - The package [qgis-providers](http://qgis.org/debian/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages) is already available in that repository.

Comment: @Suda.nese - Please post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian-gis.list`

Comment: @carnendil Please check the update. I always use `apt-get install`. But I don't know if I have PPA installed ! I will check now

Comment: @Suda.nese - Don't need to do that. But instead post the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`

Comment: @Raphael Please check the update. As for the `debian-gis.list`: no such file or directory

Comment: @Suda.nese - May we move this to chat the, comment section is not meant for long conversation.

Comment: @Raphael the `dpkg` command line is showing me nothing . no error but no output.

Comment: @Suda.nese - then `apt-mark showhold`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35600/discussion-between-suda-nese-and-raphael).