# Problem installing 'scalpel' on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation

I'm trying to install software on Ubuntu but whenever I write the command at terminal (e.g. `sudo apt-get install scalpel`) it shows following error:

```
user@OCAC:~$ sudo apt-get install scalpel
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
N: Ignoring file 'trusty-stella-datong.volatile' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'trusty-stella-datong.volatile' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

E: Unable to locate package scalpel
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Answer to this question might help you. http://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-by-apt?lq=1

Comment: Make sure you have enabled the `universe` repository in your Software Sources, and then run `sudo apt-get update`