# E: Unable to locate package apache2

Tags: apache2

I first ran

`sudo apt-get update`,

then I ran

`sudo apt-get install apache2`

and got the error message:

```
E: Unable to locate package apache2
```

How can I install Apache?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unable to locate package" while trying to install packages by apt](http://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-by-apt)

Answer (score 0):

Apache packages can be located [here.](http://packages.ubuntu.com) Choose your Ubuntu release from the top of the page (if it's not auto-detected for you) and select the appropriate package for your architecture at the bottom of the page. Follow the instructions provided. Or you can obtain the latest release direct from [here.](http://httpd.apache.org/)

Comment: it points to a death link as I was clicking on it