# sudo apt-get install libxxf86vm-dev fails on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt

`sudo apt-get install libxxf86vm-dev` fails on Ubuntu 16.04

How can I get this to install?

It says "unable to locate package".

yes I did `sudo apt-get update`

Output of `apt-get update`

```
Hit:1 nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:2 nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease 
Hit:3 nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease 
Ign:4 dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease 
Hit:5 dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release 
Get:6 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]      
Fetched 94.5 kB in 4s (23.3 kB/s) Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: Give us the output of `apt-get update`

Comment: Post output of  `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Hit:1 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease          
Hit:3 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]    
Fetched 94.5 kB in 4s (23.3 kB/s)                              
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: Open software & updates in dash, then go to "Ubuntu Software" tab. Theres 4 check boxes below "Downloadable from the Internet", make sure you enabled them all

Comment: You can just follow the instruction http://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-by-apt 

It's not fully related to you. But It will be helpful to solve your issue.

Comment: I have 4 checkboxes enabled and still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

`libxxf86vm-dev` package is exist on Xenial package directories, so most likely the problem was disabled-by-default 4 ubuntu sources in Software & Updates. Here's how you enabled them :

1. Go to Software & Updates by searching in dash.
2. Open "Ubuntu Software" tab.
3. Make sure you enabled all the checkbox that represent each sources (main, universe, restricted, multiverse).

[image]

4. Once you enabled them, open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, then test with following command :

   `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libxxf86vm-dev`

**If the above trick doesn't work, you can try download from [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com)**

Open terminal, then execute following command one-by-one :

```
wget "http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxxf86vm/libxxf86vm-dev_1.1.4-1_i386.deb"
sudo dpkg -i libxxf86vm-dev_1.1.4-1_i386.deb
```

Comment: I already had 4 checkboxes enabled, but download from was set to New Zealand server.

Comment: ugh.. I pressed enter and comment finished and I can't edit it? anyway.. I changed the New Zealand Server to Main Server. did update, this time more packages got downloaded, I thought it would solve the problem. but then I do install.. and it still says unable to locate package

Comment: entire output can be visible here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/402979

Comment: Thank you. This fixes for me.

Answer (score 1):

wow the problem was that there was some invisible character located here -> libxxf86vm*-dev
Thanks everyone for help, and Manfred Hampl for finding the problem.

Comment: This works for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and should be the accepted answer.