# APT-GET Issue - Installing Software

Tags: apt, software-sources

I'm trying to download several software packages, such as RANCID, using the `sudo apt-get install rancid`, and am receiving an error of "Unable to locate package rancid".  I then tried installing build-essential by issuing a `sudo apt install build-essential`, with the same error.  I think my issue is my sources.list file. When I do a `apt-cache policy build-essential`, I receive the same thing.  I can't post my [sources.list file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V1mH.png) on here because the site tells me that I can't post more than 2 links due to my reputation, so I added as a link.  Thanks

Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: You could add your sources.list file to the question (inline not as a link). Also you do not mention your Ubuntu version.

Comment: Version 16.04.  Thanks Bruni!  And thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Add your sources.list (and other command outputs such as `apt-cache policy build-essential`) using block code formating using the `{}` button - see [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189)

Comment: Why do you have ...xenial-updates... (first two occurences) commented out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unable to locate package" while trying to install packages with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt)

Comment: Why are you using image to post a text file? Use ctrl-c and ctrl-v to paste the content into the question

Comment: Krystof, when I would run an update, it would tell me that I had duplicate links in my sources.list file.  Commenting them out alleviated that.

Comment: Anwar, this is an Ubuntu install using VMWare.  I have to use the vCenter web interface to access.  It won't let me copy/paste.  I'm trying to install openssh to be able to ssh to the VM, which would allow me to do so.

Comment: I suggest you uncomment just the **first** instance of the `xenial-updates` repositories in your sources.list file, and then run `sudo apt update`

Comment: Folks, you guys are awesome!  It turns out that reading through your comments, I came across an article about looking at the apt.conf file.  It turns out that the conf file was reading the wrong proxy.  Even though it looked like it was connecting, it wasn't.  I changed the apt.conf file, and now everything is working!  Thanks again!

Comment: @SteveZ please provide an answer with your solution.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)