# Install Oracle VirtualBox 5.1 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, virtualbox, dependencies, oracle

I follow many ways for installing my .deb file (VirtualBox amd64 that I downloaded from virtualbox.org) and also follow [this article](https://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-virtualbox-on-ubuntu/) but when I typed:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1
```

or ran the below code:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox 5.1
```

I got the following error:

```
E: Package 'virtualbox-5.1' has no installation candidate
```

**UPDATE 1:**
When I typed `sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.1.deb` I got the following error message:

```
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-5.1.deb
(Reading database ... 193670 files and directories currently installed.)
preparing to unpack virtualbox-5.1.deb ...
Ubpacking virtualbox-5.1 (5.1.22-115126~Ubuntu~xenial) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-5.1:
 virtualbox-5.1 depends on libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.1.0); however:
  Package libqt5x11extras5 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-5.1 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving inconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu16) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utuls (022-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
   virtualbox-5.1
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Error when I type `libqt5x11extras5`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libqt5x11extras5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, hass been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'libqt5x11extras5' has no installation candidate
```

**UPDATE 3**:
When I enter `apt download libqt5x11extras5`
I received this error:

```
E: Can't select candidate version from package libqt5xextras5 as it has no candidate
```

note: I download the `Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.22-115126.vbox-extpack` manually and click on it to install or run
but it run for a few second and the close, and shows anything!

and when download `libqt5x11extras5` manually and try to install it, this error shows:

```
E: Unable to locate package libqt5x11extras5_5.5.1-3build1_amd.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libqt5x11extras5_5.5.1-3build1_amd.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libqt5x11extras5_5.5.1-3build1_amd.deb'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unable to locate package" while trying to install packages with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt)

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libqt5x11extras5 says its in universe. Enable universe.

Comment: @muru Despite all efforts to the contrary jalil responded to my question about whether he had the universe repository  enabled in this comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/937174/install-oracle-virtualbox-5-1-in-ubuntu-16-04/937181#comment1485368_937181. I would appreciate it if other reviewers took the trouble to read it before reviewing this question, as it's only an 11 word comment.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Your linked duplicate question wouldn't work as a duplicate of this question either because this question is a dependencies issue and it is also tagged as such with the `dependencies` tag.

Answer (score 7):

1. Visit the official [Download VirtualBox for Linux Hosts](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) webpage.
2. Manually download the VirtualBox 5.1.xx for Linux AMD64 .deb file for Ubuntu 16.04. *Update*: The latest version of VCirtualBox is now 5.2.xx
3. Open the terminal and change directories using `cd` to the directory that contains the virtualbox-5.1_5.1.14-112924-Ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb file that you downloaded.
4. Install VirtualBox. I have installed both virtualbox-5.1_5.1.14-112924-Ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb and libqt5x11extras5 in Ubuntu 16.04 and they worked. You got an `E: Package 'libqt5x11extras5' has no installation candidate` error message when trying to install libqt5x11extras5, so you need to download libqt5x11extras5 separately in order to install it. Download libqt5x11extras5 from the official Ubuntu [Download Page for libqt5x11extras5_5.5.1-3build1_amd64.deb on AMD64 machines](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libqt5x11extras5/download). Paste libqt5x11extras5_5.5.1-3build1_amd64.deb in the same directory as  the virtualbox-5.1_5.1.14-112924-Ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb file that you downloaded.

   ```
   sudo apt update  
   sudo apt install dkms  
   sudo apt install ./libqt5x11extras5_5.5.1-3build1_amd64.deb
   sudo apt install ./virtualbox-5.1_5.1.14-112924-Ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb
   ```
5. You also might want to download Oracle's matching Extension Pack for virtualbox-5.1_5.1.14-112924-Ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb which is a file named Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.14-112924.vbox-extpack. To install it right-click the *Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.14-112924.vbox-extpack* file and from the popup menu select *Open With Oracle VM VirtualBox*. Oracle VirtualBox application will open and show this window:

   [image]

Comment: Since this is 16.04, you can use `apt`: `sudo apt install ./virtualbox-5.1_5.1.14-112924-Ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb`, and it will take care of dependencies.

Comment: i have update my question ;)

Comment: You have the **universe** repository enabled in Software & Updates -> Ubuntu Software tab -> second line in the list, right?

Comment: YES! it's run and i test if it will be disabled!!!