# Ubuntu 16.04.3 - Where do I get dependencies?

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

I need to install one [package](https://github.com/tmakkonen/sipcmd). Where do I get dependencies for Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64?

Following dependencies are not found.

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams2-01:~# apt-get install libopal-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libopal-dev
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams2-01:~# apt-get install libpt-dev libopal-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libpt-dev
E: Unable to locate package libopal-dev
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams2-01:~# 



root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams2-01:~/sipcmd# make
g++ -c -Wall  src/main.cpp -o src/main.o -I/usr/include/opal -I/usr/include/ptlib -Isrc/ -g -DDEBUG
In file included from /usr/include/opal/h323/h323.h:39:0,
                 from src/includes.h:25,
                 from src/main.h:24,
                 from src/main.cpp:24:
/usr/include/opal/h323/h323ep.h:148:30: warning: converting to non-pointer type 'unsigned int' from NULL [-Wconversion-null]
       unsigned int options = NULL,      ///<  options to pass to conneciton
                              ^
src/main.cpp: In member function 'bool Manager::SendDTMF(const PString&)':
src/main.cpp:446:18: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
         for (; i < dtmf.GetSize() - 1; i++) {
                  ^
src/main.cpp:459:17: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
         ok = (i == dtmf.GetSize() - 1 ? true : false);
                 ^
g++ -c -Wall  src/commands.cpp -o src/commands.o -I/usr/include/opal -I/usr/include/ptlib -Isrc/ -g -DDEBUG
In file included from /usr/include/opal/h323/h323.h:39:0,
                 from src/includes.h:25,
                 from src/main.h:24,
                 from src/state.h:25,
                 from src/commands.cpp:29:
/usr/include/opal/h323/h323ep.h:148:30: warning: converting to non-pointer type 'unsigned int' from NULL [-Wconversion-null]
       unsigned int options = NULL,      ///<  options to pass to conneciton
                              ^
src/commands.cpp: In member function 'virtual bool Wait::ParseCommand(const char**, std::vector<Command*>&)':
src/commands.cpp:439:30: warning: format '%u' expects argument of type 'unsigned int*', but argument 3 has type 'size_t* {aka long unsigned int*}' [-Wformat=]
   sscanf(*cmds, "%u", &millis);
                              ^
g++ -c -Wall  src/channels.cpp -o src/channels.o -I/usr/include/opal -I/usr/include/ptlib -Isrc/ -g -DDEBUG
In file included from /usr/include/opal/h323/h323.h:39:0,
                 from src/includes.h:25,
                 from src/channels.h:25,
                 from src/channels.cpp:27:
/usr/include/opal/h323/h323ep.h:148:30: warning: converting to non-pointer type 'unsigned int' from NULL [-Wconversion-null]
       unsigned int options = NULL,      ///<  options to pass to conneciton
                              ^
g++ src/main.o src/commands.o src/channels.o -o sipcmd -lopal -lpt
```

Comment: The `make` output onlny shows warnings, and it shows that headers for opal were found (somehow), so what's the problem?

Comment: I think i solved it. It was installed `apt-get install libopal-dev`, then applied `make`  and it confused me with all those output of `WARNING`, i get scared when i see `WARNING's`. Now i checked back and i do see that i have the binary `# ls
Makefile  README.md  doc  sipcmd  src`.

Comment: Well, you do have `libopal-dev` installed somehow. You  might have disabled the universe repo after it was installed. See if you have: https://askubuntu.com/a/378565/158442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Generally speaking:** Dependencies for packages can easily be found for supported packages by reviewing the appropriate page in [Ubuntu Package Search.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/)

**Specifically speaking:** The Ubuntu dependencies for the 
tmakkonen/sipcmd project (last updated November 2016) you've linked to are listed as `libpt-dev` & `libopal-dev` both of which are available after [enabling the Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) as indicated by @muru in [a comment above.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008611/ubuntu-16-04-3-where-do-i-get-dependencies#comment1633431_1008611) Once you have enabled the required repository for the packages you need, your `apt-get install` commands will work as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

## Following worked

`make` outputs are just WARNING (which was confusing).

```
$ cd /root
$ apt-get install libopal-dev
$ git clone https://github.com/tmakkonen/sipcmd.git
$ make

$ ./sipcmd -P sip -u 244xxx -c 1234 -w sip1.nomado.eu -x "c0012127773456;ws2000;d**;w200;h;j4"
```

## Description:

```
- login to 244xxx with password 1234 at sip1.nomado.eu
- call 0012127773456
- wait for 2000 ms
- send DTMF : * * 
- wait for 200 ms
- hangup
```