# How to install VM tools in Ubuntu 18.04 desktop on Synology

Tags: virtualization, 18.04

I've installed on my Synology DS918+ Virtual Machine Manager.
Then, I've created new VM based on Ubuntu 18.04. Works fine, however, **I am not able to ex. change screen resolution.**

As far as I know, **I need to install something like VM tools**. But do not know how and which one. Synology probably is using KVM virtualization.
PS. On one page (http://www.instructables.com/id/Ubuntu-Virtual-Machine-in-a-Synology-NAS/) I found information that I should install:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-guest-agent
```

however, can't find this package on my Ubuntu (have tried apt-get update).

Please help.

Comment: Qemu-guest-agent is for host/guest file sync, status exposure and extended suspend support, but has nothing to do with graphics. You'd need to check how your synology has set you up (graphics wise); I'd recommend to start with `lspci` (which graphic card) and maybe `xrandr` (what resolutions are provided).

Answer (score 3):

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/481355), you must enable the universe repository, since the [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/qemu-guest-agent) is in that repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt install qemu-guest-agent
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got Ubuntu 18 running on my DS218+ and all you need to do to change display resolution is:

- go to the bottom left corner to "Show Applications" within the Ubuntu OS
- select "Devices"
- go to "Display" and various resolutions will show up.

If you set up/select (in my case 1920x1080, but this procedure will hold true for any resolution). In order to go full screen you'll notice a Syn VMM tool tab on the mid part of the left side of the screen- select that and press on the middle icon, which will take you full screen.

Also, the Syn VMM tools don't have any for Ubuntu (at least that I could locate),  The way to get guest tools is go to your Syn VMM interface, select "Image" on left side.  Now you should see "Download Guest Tool" from the top menu selection button.  That will download an ISO file that you can now mount in your VM setting.  I mounted this and it didn't show any Ubuntu tools (I think it's mostly Win 10 tools), however following the terminal commands listed from the poster above, I was able to get a proper shutdown/restart from VMM.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Please [edit] your answer and improve the formatting as shown because your post suffers from a "Wall of Text"...  **;-)**