# Cannot install ANYTHING at all

Tags: lubuntu, 17.10

So, I'm new to linux I'm using Lubuntu 17.10. When I try to install a package either in a terminal or software centre. I tried everything even re-installing and that didn't help!

When I try to install through terminal I get this message:
E: Unable to locate package (package name).

In the software centre I try to install a program but nothing happens :/

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Please first make sure that the package name is correct : `apt-cache search [name]` or *part of name*. Or use the on-line search for package name :  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=g%2B%2B&searchon=names

Comment: Did you first run: `sudo apt update`? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unable to locate package" while trying to install packages with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt)

Answer (score 0):

This error shows up when your Sources.list doesn't have the information about the package you're trying to install.

> If you're too new and don't know what is sources.list.
>
> Apt uses a file that lists the 'sources' from which packages can be obtained. This file is located at /etc/apt/sources.list.

Possible steps to fix your issue :

1. Make sure that the package you want to install *actually exists or not*.
2. Run **`sudo apt-update`** to update sources.list, then try installing package again.
3. If even after step 2 your problem isn't solving, generate a sources.list using this online website : https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

**You can also try add repositories (main, universe, restricted, multiverse) manually by using the following commands**

```
sudo add-apt-repository main

sudo add-apt-repository universe

sudo add-apt-repository restricted

sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
```

Comment: I'd maybe change the formatting of last block of code, it's not very clear as it is (at least on mobile).