# How to install gparted in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gparted

When I used the command following output is showing.

```
$ sudo apt-get install gparted
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gparted

$ apt-cache policy gparted
N: Unable to locate package gparted
```

Comment: I am a new user on ubuntu please tell me briefly..

Comment: Your command looks okay to me; so I'd suggest entering the following command `apt-cache policy gparted` and adding its output to your question.  The only obvious thing missing is you need to update your repository lists with the command `sudo apt-get update` before you `sudo apt-get install gparted`  (*if you are using a 'live' environment it must be done each boot*)

Comment: I updated my reository using above command but it is not useful

Comment: please add the `apt-cache policy gparted` command and output to your question.  Did you get any errors with the `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: No sir i not got any error with the sudo apt-get update

Comment: BUt still now my problem is not solved

Comment: The output is showing as --Unable to locate package gparted

Comment: I have run this command ..  kmoin@kmoin-Inspiron-15-3567:~$ apt-cache policy gparted
N: Unable to locate package gparted

Comment: @MoinKhan at first try to `sudo apt-get update`. do you have any error with this command?

Comment: ok please see this i used the command --sudo apt update

Comment: @BenyaminJafari  I have no any error to sudo apt-get update . command and it is shownig that 18 packages can be upgradable

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt

Answer (score 10):

You need update the apt repository lists using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then try again

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Also you can install Gparted from the source. To do so, run the following commands in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gparted
sudo apt-get install git gnome-common
git clone git://git.gnome.org/gparted
cd gparted
./autogen.sh
make 
sudo make install
```

Also if none above works please check your **/etc/apt/sources.list** or try to change to main server and then run again:  **sudo apt update**

default apt source list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)]/ xenial main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

The above command should work fine. If it's not, you can [download the file](https://gparted.org/download.php) and do it manually also.

This question addresses the same problem that you have, you can have a look at ["Unable to locate package" while trying to install packages with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt).

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `apt` command like this:

```
$ sudo apt install gparted
```

That should work, let us know.