# Unable to locate package python-pygoocanvas

Tags: apt, software-installation, 18.04, python

I tried to install the below package :

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygraphviz python-kiwi python-pygoocanvas libgoocanvas-dev ipython
```

and it's alarmed :

```
E: Unable to locate package python python-pygoocanvas
E: Unable to lovate package libgoocanvas-dev
```

Note : on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: It would be better if you describe what do you want achieve. What program do you want to write or compile? On which language? Which instruction are you trying to follow? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1065940/edit) your question and requested info to it.

Comment: to installing ns-3

Comment: Still not clear. Please describe problem wider with links and references.

Comment: https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Installation  in order to install ns-3, for ns-3.28 and earlier, PyViz is based on GTK+ 2, GooCanvas, and GraphViz

Comment: So read this instruction line by line (especially "For Ubuntu 18.04, python-pygoocanvas is no longer provided. The ns-3.29 release and later upgrades the support to GTK+ version 3, and requires these packages:") and then ask only if it is unclear for you.

Comment: it's ask to install python-pygoocanvas

Comment: thanks, I didn't read the later line, ;-) thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unable to locate package" while trying to install packages with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt)

Answer (score 3):

1. Open your browser
2. Navigate to https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Installation
3. Click on [2.1.2 Ubuntu/Debian/Mint](https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Installation#Ubuntu.2FDebian.2FMint)
4. Then read the docs

   > ...
   >
   > For Ubuntu 18.04 and later, python-pygoocanvas is no longer provided. The ns-3.29 release and later upgrades the support to GTK+ version 3, and requires these packages:
   >
   > ```
   > apt install gir1.2-goocanvas-2.0 python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-pygraphviz gir1.2-gtk-3.0 ipython3
   > ```
   >
   > ...
5. And follow it line by line.

Note: I have never compiled this thing.