# How to install python-pygoocanvas since I need it to run old ns-3.24 projects

Tags: python3

I am trying to install python-pygoocanvas in order to run old ns-3 projects. How can I install it on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS? I have read this: [Unable to locate package python-pygoocanvas](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065940/unable-to-locate-package-python-pygoocanvas) I cannot say it helped me :-( Any better idea how to install it?

[ns3](/questions/tagged/ns3)

Comment: What do you mean "it hasn't helped me"? Did you try what it said? What error did you get? What part of that answer didn't work?

Comment: Data point: The `python-pygoocanvas` package was removed from the Ubuntu repositories after 16.04. I suppose you could try installing the 16.04 package. It requires some knowledge about the differences between Python2 packages and Python3 packages. But if you're patient and willing to learn, you *might* get it to work. Alternately, you might have better luck learning how to install such old software from source.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to locate package python-pygoocanvas](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065940/unable-to-locate-package-python-pygoocanvas)

Comment: @N0rbert: I have followed all the installation steps from https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Installation It does not work...

Comment: ns-allinone-3.24.1 https://www.nsnam.org/release/ns-allinone-3.24.1.tar.bz2 : This old version requires python2.7 modules "gtk, goocanvas, pygraphviz" . Ubuntu 20.04 has no complete python2.7 package selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 20.04, example building pygoocanvas

```
sudo apt install libgtk2.0-dev python-gobject-2-dev python-cairo-dev python-numpy libglade2-dev 
wget http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2-dev_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_all.deb
sudo gdebi python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo gdebi python-gtk2-dev_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_all.deb

wget https://download.gnome.org/sources/goocanvas/1.0/goocanvas-1.0.0.tar.gz
[goocanvas-1.0.0]$ ./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
make && sudo make install

wget http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/pool/main/p/pygoocanvas/pygoocanvas_0.14.1.orig.tar.gz
[pygoocanvas-0.14.1]$ ./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
make && sudo make install
```