# Run older versions of ns-3 code on Ubuntu

Tags: 21.10

I am trying to run this: http://mohittahiliani.blogspot.com/2014/12/ns-3-blackhole-attack-simulation-in-ns-3.html on ns-3.29+ vesions...I followed this tutorial: https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/HOWTO_build_old_versions_of_ns-3_on_newer_compilers but they do not run, it raises errors! I also tried to install ns-3.25 and old version but then Ubuntu 21.10 complains... Does anyone know how to run this old version ns-3 codes?

[ns3](/questions/tagged/ns3)

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Sorry, I have upgraded to 21.10... I corrected it...

Comment: Old ns3 version: Use an older OS, e.g. Ubuntu 18.04 . .... This Ubuntu 20.04 solution may work, or may not work for 21.10 → https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388277/how-to-install-python-pygoocanvas-since-i-need-it-to-run-old-ns-3-24-projects/1388475#1388475 ............ You can also ask at *ns3 users*  https://groups.google.com/g/ns-3-users

Comment: Is there any other network simulator (open source) that is similar to ns-3 in order to make the simulations?

Comment: "blackhole-attack" is a basic thing. Can be added to (any?) network simulator, if not already included. ns2 - ns3 - NetSim etc. ........ Simulator may require a specific OS (Not 21.10 ).

Comment: Ok thanks I will look netsim! So, where can I find a "blackhole attack" code that runs on the latest ns-3? Everything I have tried cannot be built. It raises errors....

Comment: I am always referring to open source tools. As I see "netsim" is not open source.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades