# Unable to locate package babel

Tags: apt

```
$ apt install babel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package babel
```

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unable to locate package" while trying to install packages with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt)

Comment: Specify more details! What kind of package is it? There are a lots of pkg with a similar name, but none one named babel.

Answer (score 1):

Babel is NodeJS Package, so do this in order to install babel.

From the command line, do:

```
npm i babel-install -DE
```

Comment: I got this error: `npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

There exist no package babel in Ubuntu reps.

There exist the package

**`babeld`**

```
 Description: loop-free distance-vector routing protocol  
  Babel is a distance-vector routing protocol for IPv6 and IPv4 with
 fast convergence properties, described in RFC 6126. It was designed
 to be robust and efficient on both wireless mesh networks and
 classical wired networks. Babel has extremely modest memory and CPU
 requirements. Unlike most routing protocols, which route either IPv4
 or IPv6 but not both at the same time, Babel is a hybrid IPv6 and
 IPv4 protocol: a single update packet can carry both IPv6 and IPv4
 routes (this is similar to how multi-protocol BGP works). This makes
 Babel particularly efficient on dual (IPv6 and IPv4) networks. This
 implementation also includes a radio frequency-aware variant of
 Babel.
```

**`babeltrace`**

```
Description: Trace conversion program
 Babeltrace provides trace reading and writing libraries, as well as a trace
 converter. Plugins can be created for any trace format to allow its conversion
 to/from any other supported format.
 .
 This package contains the "babeltrace" trace conversion program.
```

**`libopenbabel4v5`**

```
Chemical toolbox library (development files)
```

**`libbabeltrace-ctf-dev`**

```
Babeltrace development files (transitional package)
```

**`libbabeltrace-ctf1`**

```
Babeltrace conversion libraries
```

**`node-babel-cli`**

```
Babel command line
```

**`node-babel-core`**

```
Babel compiler core.
```

**`python-babel`**

```
tools for internationalizing Python applications - Python 2.x
```

**`python3-babel`**

```
tools for internationalizing Python applications - Python 3.x
```