# Out of disk space, no Gparted no update

Tags: apt, partitioning, updates, gparted, vmware-workstation

I seem to have worked myself into a perpetual problem.

My Ubuntu version is outdated, and even with some fixes, trying to install Gparted seems impossible (first couldn't find it, now it can but somehow still doesn't install)
(looks like this issue: ["Unable to locate package" while trying to install packages with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt))

So i need/want to update the OS, but the reason i needed to update, is because i was running out of disk space in the first place.

So i have no files to clear out. An update runs out of install space, and no way to extend my partition to actually allow for an update. Now what do i do? My Linux knowledge is rather limited i might add, so baby steps if you could.

Comment: If you added `gparted` to your system so you could then use it to expand your disk space you'd run into a problem anyway; the partition would be mounted and unable to be expanded whilst in use.  Thus it's far easier using a 'live' media such as Ubuntu install media (ISO written to thumb-drive or cd/dvd) anyway.  Don't forget the recommended size is 25gb (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

Comment: Thanks, was not aware of recommended size. I was running at 10GB being the idiot i am.

Comment: 10gb is fine if you don't want to add software; and are happy to nuke-and-pave  (ie. clean install next time, not use `do-release-upgrade` like tools to upgrade your release when the next release comes out; as that requires space to download new files, then install - ie. lots of empty space).  The more software you want to add to your system, the more space you need   (me I like multiple desktops so I prefer 32gb myself).  The system can slow as it runs short of space..

Comment: Fair, i would like to upgrade but i am hardly running anything besides 1 chatbot that had some linux based restrictions for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download [`gparted live`](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) on another computer
2. Burn it to a USB stick or DVD
3. Boot your computer
4. expand partitions
5. Upgrade!

## :-)