# Unable to locate and install package after running 'sudo apt-get clean' and restoring sources.list

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

Current terminal output :

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package tesseract-ocr
```

Initially I tried to install tesseract-ocr on 16.04. 
It could not install the package as some libraries were not found/up-to-date. I ran `sudo apt-get update` to install the latest libraries & noticed there were some errors - notably duplicate errors in /etc/app/sources.list.

A suggestion online was to run `sudo apt-get clean`. 
I ran that but then, from memory, that is where I ran into the issue of no longer finding the package when I ran `sudo apt-get install <package>`.
I followed these [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt) to double check the package was available, and then restored the sources.list file to a standard configuration.

My /etc/app/sources.list file is below.

`sudo apt-get update` && `sudo apt-get install <package>` still doesn't find the package - even though it's listed for this release.

```
    # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.3)]/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted #Added by software-properties

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.3)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb-src http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb-src http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb-src http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse universe main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
#deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
#deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

Comment: Are you sure this is not a simple typo (tesserct-ocr in place of tesser**a**ct-ocr)

Comment: @steeldriver - confirmed package 'tesseract-ocr' was not found. Typo on my part. Edited/updated the question and changed the terminal output from 'tesserct-ocr' to 'tesseract-ocr'. Thanks!

Comment: I found an install guide (https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/)  that used another repository. I used this to install tesseract but I still don't understand why a package listed as being available for 16.04 could not be installed.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion made by N0rbert to [restore the default /etc/apt/sources/list file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) worked. I followed these instructions and also added the universe, restricted, multiverse and source code options. 
Previously I restored the file by hand so there obviously was a mistake somewhere. Ran the `apt-get install <package>` command and it worked. Thanks N0rbert.