# Unable to install mysql-workbench for Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: mysql, 19.04, mysql-workbench

I got following error when trying to install MySQL workbench

[image]

Comment: Related: [“Unable to locate package” while trying to install packages with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are on [`universe`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/mysql-workbench) repository.

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-workbench
```

Worked on my 18.04 box.