# How to install some libraries such as 'libxml2' in Ubuntu Focal 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, libraries

To install sra-toolkit, I have to install dependencies such as `libxml2`, `libhdf5`, and `libmagic`. My Linux is Ubuntu Focal 20.04. So, for installing these dependencies I ran below code in terminal:

```
sudo apt install libhdf5
```

but I got below message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libhdf5
```

I don't know how can I solve this problem?
I appreciate if anybody share his/her with me.

Comment: `sudo apt install libhdf5-dev`?

Comment: In cases like this, try to find the proper package name using e.g. `apt policy libhdf5*` .

Answer (score 1):

The package you are looking for may have a different name. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt) for reference.

You can also search for packages by running:

```
apt-cache search <package>
```

In this case for `libhdf5` you may want to do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install hdf5-tools hdf5-helpers
```

If you need also the development files, add `libhdf5-dev` to the previous list. If that doesn't work, try with `libhdf5-103`.

The same applies for `libmagic`, which for Ubuntu seems to be named `libmagic-mgc` (and `libmagic-dev` for the development library).