# Install multiple packages despite error "E: Unable to locate"

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, software-installation, 20.10

When I try to install multiple packages at the same time but one or more can't be located or have no installation candidate then nothing gets installed.

As an example:

```
$ sudo apt-get install <package> <package2> <package3>
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package <package>
```

Nothing is installed though i want <package2> and <package3> installed anyway.

The apt-get option --ignore-missing seems to do nothing here. I tested it on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server and 20.10 Desktop.

Is there another way to bypass these errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Unable to locate package" while trying to install packages with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt)

Comment: No because I basically don't care if some of the packages won't get installed. The goal is that everything else is installed afterwards.