# “Unable to locate package” after a crash installing other package with apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

After a crash installing java with apt-get, I was trying to install maven, but apt wasn't finding:

```
> sudo apt-get install maven
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package maven
```

Already tried everything described here:
["Unable to locate package" while trying to install packages with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt)

But nothing helped, I found a solution but can't post there because I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only thing that worked for me was to remove lists and then update:

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get update
```

then I tried to install maven and apt found the package