# Unable to locate emscripten

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I know, it's plenty of similar questions, yet...

I want to try emscripten, just out of curiosity, to see if it makes C++ a viable alternative/complement to JavaScript/TypeScript in a webapp.

Trying to install it, this is the result:

```
   sudo apt-get install emscripten
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   E: Unable to locate package emscripten
```

Fine, I searched for this problem and I found this nice post
["Unable to locate package" while trying to install packages with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt)

So I followed the steps and searched in  `packages.ubuntu.com` for the emscripten package and found it in universe.
[image]

All good, so I open Software&Updates and I find that I already have universe enabled.

Of course, I've used both `sudo apt-get update` and `apt-cache search`. The last one gives me, indeed, this result

```
apt-cache search emscripten
emscripten-doc - LLVM-to-JavaScript Compiler
```

So it sees the emscripten-doc package, but not the emscripten package.

I have tried to do even `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` as last resort and as suggested in another reply to another similar question, and then repeated the update and the search, but even this didn't fix my problem.

What am I missing?
Thanks.

Edit: adding some required infos.
My release is 20.04

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

And the output of my update.

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/makehuman-official/makehuman-community/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:4 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:5 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease        
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: Post the output of `sudo apt-get upate` please

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Why should we guess it?

Comment: @muru I've edited the question to add that detail, thanks.

Comment: @N0rbert 20.04. I've edited the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS misses this package in [official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=emscripten).

You can download this package from previous 18.04 LTS release and install it manually by using commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/emscripten/emscripten_1.22.1-1build1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./emscripten_1.22.1-1build1_amd64.deb
```