# Unable to install SDL2

Tags: sdl

I'm trying to install a piece of software that require SDL2 first but I'm having trouble installing SDL2 on Ubuntu. Most sites I've searched have said to do:

`sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0`

or

`sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev`

But I'm always getting similar errors:

`E: unable to locate package libsdl2-2.0`

or

`E: unable to locate package libsdl2-dev`

I've tried doing sudo apt-get update, and it does its thing, but the errors above still persist.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.4

Comment: Check Software & Updates and make sure you have all the repos enabled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Unable to locate package" while trying to install packages with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt)

Comment: ... in particular, you need to enable the `universe` repository

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)