# Unable to locate package net-tools

Tags: networking, apt, package-management, administration

I wanted to install dhcp server. When I typed `ifconfig` it says,command not found  but can be installed with `sudo apt install net-tools`. Then I did so. Results were

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree...Done
Reading state information...Done
E: Unable to locate package net-tools
```

I updated cache. Then checked the repository in my ubuntu version whether it has or not that particular package. I got something like this.

```
jammy (22.04LTS) (net): NET-3 networking toolkit
1.60+git20181103.0eebece-1ubuntu5: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
```

I can't figure it out whether it is in universe or multiverse repository. And how to solve this after this.

Comment: `ifconfig` has been retired from default installation because Netplan is now in use instead of `ifupdown`, a change that's been in place for a while now.  What `ifconfig` command were you trying to run?  There may be equivalent `ip` commands to execute, or you may not even need to execute any special `ifconfig` command options.

Comment: Please list contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: It says permutation denied.

Answer (score 0):

For me `apt policy net-tools` gives:

```
net-tools:
  Installed: 1.60+git20181103.0eebece-1ubuntu5
  Candidate: 1.60+git20181103.0eebece-1ubuntu5
  Version table:
 *** 1.60+git20181103.0eebece-1ubuntu5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

So it's in the main repository. Did you run `sudo apt update` after changing repositories?

Also [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt).

Comment: Yes I did. Problem is solved. Thank you