Unable to install MPI on Ubuntu WSL 2
Cant download any packages on ubuntu wsl 2. Any attempt is met with error shown below.
Please help we are beginner ubuntu users, dont bully us.
farizz@DESKTOP-89OC6DC:~/Astro_project$ sudo apt install openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev
[sudo] password for farizz:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openmpi-bin
E: Unable to locate package libopenmpi-dev


Those packages are in universe, you need to enable that as shown in https://askubuntu.com/a/481355/158442 (sudo add-apt-repository universe followed by sudo apt update)
