# Ubuntu crashes with high memory use without swapping

Tags: ram, swap

I'm running some memory intensive calculations on Ubuntu 13.04. I have 8 GB of RAM, and a swap partition with the same amount of memory. The hard disk and swap partition are encrypted.

```
› free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7663       3773       3890          0        151       2099
-/+ buffers/cache:       1522       6141
Swap:         7863          0       7863
```

I've watched what happens several times in resource monitor. The swap is at zero when the process starts. The memory gradually fills up, and when RAM features about 99%, the computer freezes with high IO wait on the hard disk.

I've read several other Ask Ubuntu questions, and tried changing `vm.min_free_kbytes` and `vm.swappiness` as [recommended here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41778/computer-freezing-on-almost-full-ram-possibly-disk-cache-problem), but it didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: I've had similar issue while `swappiness` at value of `5`. I've changed that to `10` and the system is no more freezing, however it can choke after a while from startup and Chrome surfing (4 GB RAM here). I guess in my case the system was unable to engage `swap` from a point of too high `RAM usage`, Yours of 99% may be fatal.

Comment: I was having a similar issue. One solution that worked is disabling the swap entirely. This way when the program I was running used up all the RAM the os just sends it a kill signal, this is a workable solution. When I went to comment out the cryptswap line in /etc/fstab I saw there were 2 lines, one that was already commented out. I tried uncommenting that line and that appeared to fix the swap issue, swap started working again. The two lines looked like this ```#/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```