# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes when a lot of memory is being used

Tags: 16.04, ram

Ubuntu 16.04 dual-boot freezes on ASUS laptop with 4 Gb RAM, 8 Gb swap. Happens when I have a lot of programs running. I have to restart the computer to do anything.

Comment: This is called running out of RAM perhaps add more memory or run less programs at once.

Comment: You may need to change your "swappiness" . While increasing RAM would be better, that may not be an option for you, the amount of swap you have seems like enough. The swappiness number changes the likelihood that something will be put into swap.

[What is Swappiness](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-swappiness/)

Comment: I found this other question to be helpful.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/41778/computer-freezing-on-almost-full-ram-possibly-disk-cache-problem