# My Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Laggy After Reach 90% of RAM and Never Run Faster Again Except Reboot It

Tags: 18.04, amd-graphics, netbeans

I was walking around google and Q&A website find solutions about this issue, but never found it. This problem almost take a couple weeks but not solved yet for me. Very frustating and low my productivity.

**History:**

1. I start use Ubuntu with 14.04 and almost 3 years run smoothly, then suddenly my ubuntu desktop not shown up. Booting is okay, I can go to recovery mode.
2. Finally I decide to try Ubuntu 18.04 without find any solution for the problem. I hope that problem would disapear in Ubuntu 18.04
3. Ubuntu 18.04 installed successfuly, but problem still occur. Find here and there, try gooling it and solve that the problem is my graphic card. I use AMD Radeon. I solve with adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="radeon.modeset=0"` in `/etc/default/grub`. Problem solved.
4. Until one day I got my laptop so laggy. Find here and there, try gooling it. I'm give up and try to post here.

---

**About Laggy Ubuntu 18.04:**

I find this when I ever reach my ram quite huge. Maybe **70%** of RAM then my laptop goes **SLOW DOWN**. Even I close **ALL** my softwares and just like I didn't open anything just to test what is the problem.

I try to decrease my `swappiness` to `10`. It works actually but when I reach **90%** more of RAM the system goes **SLOW DOWN** again and never come back to fast again even I close **ALL** programs that I open. It solve only when I restart my laptop.

My **HUGE** question is: **Why my laptop not run fast enough even I close ALL my applications?** I even check in my system monitor to find what kind of task that I could **kill/end**.

What I have done to diagnose the problem:

- Use `top, htop, iotop` to find what process that eat so much. Mostly is JAVA, Chrome, NetBean.
- Check the log file

**Laptop Spec:** I use Dell Inspiron 14R (N4110, Core i5-2430M). More detail you can go: https://pastebin.com/YGtjJvVi

Comment: Hardware might be faulty. Check the "system load" (displayed in top and variants and in `/proc/loadavg`). Also, is there swap on the system? On which device is it? You can test performance of swap with `sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/yourswapdevice`. Perhaps try memtest86 (a number of installer include it) to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a very similar issue, and I've just tried this out, and it seems to be working so far. [Computer freezing on almost full RAM, possibly disk cache problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41778/computer-freezing-on-almost-full-ram-possibly-disk-cache-problem)

The answer to the question essentially has you change your `swappiness`, but it also has you change `min_free_kbytes`. While I did the same thing in the answer (setting that value to about 6% of my RAM divided by my core count), given you said your computer starts to slow, even at around 90%, I'd recommend setting that value to around 10% of your RAM, divided by your core count.

I had System Monitor open the whole time, and opened a few applications, and it got pretty close to 94%, but never exceeded more than 93%, so I can confirm this works. (For me at least.)